# Azure Mobile Services Endpoint not found (.NET backend)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I am building a simple expense tracking system. The code works fine when I run it locally but when i try to connect to the endpoint in Azure I get a 404 error . I even tried completely removing the mobile service and republishing it but it only works on my local machine.

```
spoofy@spoofers:~$ curl -v https://mxpense.azure-mobile.net/tables/Expense
* About to connect() to mxpense.azure-mobile.net port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 191.236.80.12... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using RC4-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=WA; L=Redmond; O=Microsoft; OU=OrganizationName; CN=*.azurewebsites.net
*        start date: 2014-03-24 21:01:22 GMT
*        expire date: 2016-03-23 21:01:22 GMT
*        subjectAltName: mxpense.azure-mobile.net matched
*        issuer: DC=com; DC=microsoft; DC=corp; DC=redmond; CN=MSIT Machine Auth CA 2
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /tables/Expense HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: mxpense.azure-mobile.net
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=11de5874c445a15c401ea654cfeb62ad8ed363d5c21bc48e2b33658554d05d9b;Path=/;Domain=mxpense.azure-mobile.net
< Date: Fri, 01 Aug 2014 00:12:03 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host mxpense.azure-mobile.net left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

I seed the database with some sample data which i see in the Azure SQL DB so I know the data is there

[image: sql db]

And of course my seed method

```
    List<Expense> expenses = new List<Expense>{ new Expense { Id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Amount = 7.77, Client = "Cisco", Location = "Houston,tx", Date = DateTime.UtcNow},
    new Expense {Id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),Amount = 10.99, Client= "Microsoft", Location = "Remond, WA", Date = DateTime.UtcNow}};

    foreach (Expense exp in expenses)
    {
        context.Set<Expense>().Add(exp);
    }
    base.Seed(context);
```

The class def for the object

```
    public class Expense: EntityData
    {
        public double Amount { get; set; }

        public ExpenseCurrency? Currency { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

        public string Vender { get; set; }

        public ExpenseType? Type { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }

        public string Client { get; set; }

        public string Project { get; set; }

        public bool? PersonalExpense { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE**

it seems the Azure Mobile Services SDK is requesting the wrong path. Instead of requesting http://{service name}.azure-mobile.net/api/Expenses  it is requesting https://{service name}.azure-mobile.net/tables/Expenses

here is the init

```
private MobileServiceCollection<Expense, Expense> expenseCollection;
private IMobileServiceTable<Expense> expenseTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<Expense>();
```

and here is where the exception is thrown

```
expenseCollection = await expenseTable.ToCollectionAsync();
```

**Update 2**

the expensecontroller class was requested..

```
public class ExpensesController : ApiController
{
    private mXpenseContext db = new mXpenseContext();

    // GET: api/Expenses
    public IQueryable<Expense> GetExpenses()
    {
        return db.Expenses;
    }

    // GET: api/Expenses/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Expense))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExpense(string id)
    {
        Expense expense = await db.Expenses.FindAsync(id);
        if (expense == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(expense);
    }

    // PUT: api/Expenses/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutExpense(string id, Expense expense)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != expense.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(expense).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ExpenseExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Expenses
    [ResponseType(typeof(Expense))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostExpense(Expense expense)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Expenses.Add(expense);

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (ExpenseExists(expense.Id))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = expense.Id }, expense);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Expenses/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Expense))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteExpense(string id)
    {
        Expense expense = await db.Expenses.FindAsync(id);
        if (expense == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Expenses.Remove(expense);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(expense);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool ExpenseExists(string id)
    {
        return db.Expenses.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly check the image.

Comment: Can you post the Controller class? probably ExpenseController.cs

Answer (score 1):

By default Controllers in Mobile Services (.Net) inherit from TableController as shown by your error message where its looking for a route to /tables/expenses . As your controller inherits from ApiController (perfectly ok as per webApi) you should be able to add a route attribute to get the desired result.

```
// GET: api/Expenses
[Route("api")]
public IQueryable<Expense> GetExpenses()
{
    return db.Expenses;
}

// GET: api/Expenses/5
[Route("api/{id}"]
[ResponseType(typeof(Expense))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExpense(string id)
{
    Expense expense = await db.Expenses.FindAsync(id);
    if (expense == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(expense);
}
```

Comment: Updated the Expense controller and im still having the same issue. I suspect the problem is with my client configuration and not the controller class.  The windows phone client connecting to the service is requesting the wrong path.

Comment: it does sound like that might be the problem. I usually test the service using Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and adding breakpoint on the GET method then you can know for sure the service is performing as expected. Let me know how you get on

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue was with my controller. It was inheriting from ApiController but switching it to TableController resolved the issue. When scaffolding make sure to use the 'windows mobile services table controller' option

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should show up under the help page which you can see both locally and while hosted. If hosted then use your master key as password (username doesn't matter).

TableControllers are hooked up under the /tables/* path whereas all other controllers are hooked up under /api/* For TableControllers you can use the client table APIs, for all others you can use the custom API.

Thanks,

Henrik